# Unable to load jupyterlab via password mode in html iframe

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

I can load jupyterlab in passwordless mode in the iframe
Jupyterlab has set up the pwd login mode. You can directly open the login link in the browser and enter pwd to log in. But after I embedded jupyterlab in iframel and entered pwd, the page did not respond.

This is my configuration

```
    c.ServerApp.disable_check_xsrf = True
    c.ServerApp.allow_remote_access = True
    c.ServerApp.port = 7778
    c.ServerApp.open_browser= False
    c.ServerApp.ip = '0.0.0.0'  or c.ServerApp.ip = '*'
    c.ServerApp.token = ''
    c.ServerApp.password = 'sha1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    c.ServerApp.allow_origin='*'
     c.ServerApp.tornado_settings = {
         'headers': {
           'Content-Security-Policy': "frame-ancestors 'self' *"
          }
    }
```